# Is it possible to make two different primary keys in MySQL to reference each other?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:
1. Incident with case_id as Primary Key and
2. Vehicle with vehicle_no as Primary Key.
Is it possible to make vehicle_no to reference to case_id?

Comment: You should run `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table 1>` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table 2>` and paste your table-creation DDL in your question to provide context.

Comment: This is too broad to answer sensibly.

Comment: Making a Foreign Key is too broad? Good I didn't know that.

Comment: @RahulKumar: Making a foreign key is actually pretty trivial.  Unfortunately, you haven't explained what you've tried and how it didn't work.  We can't help you if you can't describe the problem.  If all you need is the MySQL documentation for foreign keys, that's pretty easy to find on Google: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 1):

It is.  Though it's a bit strange for two seemingly different entities to share one key.  This normally happens with related entities.  (It's especially concerning that they're named entirely different things, this could lead to confusion later on.)  But in any event, the same pattern works.

You would have your `Incident` table:

```
Incident
----------
case_id    PK    auto-increment
some_other_field
etc.
```

This would create a normal auto-increment key like any other.  Then your `Vehicle` table would simply have a foreign key that's also its primary key:

```
Vehicle
----------
vehicle_no    PK    FK to Incident
another_field
etc.
```

When inserting into `Vehicle`, you just need to provide that `INSERT` statement with a valid value for its foreign key, just like inserting any other value into a foreign key field.

Comment: I have already tried this. MySQL doesn't allows to do this.

Comment: @RahulKumar: It doesn't?  That's very surprising.  How did you define your tables and what was the error?

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient normalization. A vehicle can be related to more than one incident, surely? and an incident can involve more than one vehicle? So you don't want to relate a vehicle row directly to a case, or *vice versa*. What you need is a third table, with `{case_id,vehicle_id}` pairs.